# How to deploy a file to group of servers according to branch wise in Git

Tags: git, jenkins, ansible, jenkins-plugins

We are maintaining a Git repo with different branches to store the application wise scripts. Currently we have a manual parameterised Jenkins job, there we will manually pass the group we need the script to be deployed to, but I would like to automate this using a Jenkins Job. Whenever someone commits new file/Scripts to any branch in Git, it has to be deployed to those specific groups of application servers.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "branch wise" and "application wise"?

Comment: i mean to say we have different application servers in our production and have created a separate branches with application names to store scripts related to those app servers. Suppose if we added a new script for one of the app server in git branch, it has to be deployed to all the group of servers which are related to that application servers.

Comment: You need to add webhook's in your git. This webhooks must be the url to trigger the job in jenkins. Search on internet for git webhook and jenkins build trigger.